# Access 2010 Optimizing a bloated query

Tags: query-optimization, ms-access-2010

I have to have this query produce a monthly average availability for a selection of equipment. The query looks pretty ugly and rather bloated and I'm wondering if there's something I can do to make it better.

Right now I have an Expression column representing each month. In each month, take January for example, I need to check if the maintenance period occurred within the month, started before the month but ended during, started during the month but ended outside, completely encapsulates the month (if Jan 2012, then started maintenance Dec 2011 ended Feb 2012),  or not count it because it was fully operational throughout the month.

So as you can see checking these 4 cases and doing calculations afterwards really bloats up one month, let alone 12! So I'm just looking for a suggestion if there's something more I can be doing. I'm not afraid of some RnD if someone has articles they can point me towards. If this approach is not overly bad I don't mind, I would just like to do better if its possible.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If you have not got too many records, this could be a case for a User Defined Function.

Answer (score 0):

can't you just do a simple crosstab query in MS Access?